# Discord.js Member Image not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

**My Code**

```
const Canvas = require("canvas")
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const background = "https://i.ibb.co/02ssPDK/Music-1200x670.png"
const dim = {
    height: 675,
    width: 1200,
    margin: 50
}
const av = {
    size: 256,
    x: 480,
    y: 170
}

const Image = async (member) => {
    let username = member.user.username
    let discrim = member.user.discriminator
    let avatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: "png", dynamic: false, size: av.size})
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(dim.width, dim.height)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    //Draw
    const backgimage = await Canvas.loadImage(background)
    ctx.drawImage(backgimage, 0, 0)
    //Black box
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"
    ctx.fillRect(dim.margin, dim.margin, dim.width - 2 * dim.margin, dim.height - 2 * dim.margin)

    const avimg = await Canvas.loadImage(avatarURL)
    ctx.save()

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(av.x + av.size /2, av.h + av.size /2, av.size/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.clip()
    ctx.drawImage(avimg, av.x, av.y)
    ctx.restore()

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), "welcome.png")
    return attachment

}

module.exports = Image
```

***DaError***

When a user join my channel, only the background image and the text come, but not the user's Image.
.......................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code: `ctx.arc(av.x + av.size /2, av.h + av.size /2, av.size/2, 0, Math.PI*2, true)`

You should type `av.y` instead of `av.h` because inside `av` variable, it doesn't contains `h`.